# Where are you going if you killed the Priest after you got The instrument of forgiveness from him?

Tags: catholicism, forgiveness, priests

This is one of the most known contradiction which I know in  Christianity doctrine , Many Christians belives with the **instrument of forgiveness** which they received it from priest  in order to forgive them for their sins , Now my question here is :

Assume someone killed priest after he got the instrument of forgiveness ,Fire or paradise for that killer ?

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of *instrument of forgiveness*. Could you provide a source so I can be certain what you are talking about?

Comment: @ninthamigo, Probably of my bad english , I meant the ticket of forgivness , this is well known at christianity

Comment: I understand that language barriers can be tough, but I think I know less about the ticket of forgiveness than instrument of forgiveness. Do you mean "words of absolution" where after confession a priest tells you "I absolve you from your sins"? See: https://forums.catholic.com/t/words-of-absolution/95466/2

Comment: @ninthamigo, Great , this is what I meant , Why christian asked priest to forgive himة Why this mediation ?   , Why he didn't ask God directly to forgive hime ?

Comment: Since this is perhaps more for Roman Catholics than all Christians, I suggest that you edit your title to say: *Is it acceptable to sin by killing the priest who just absolved you of your sins? (Catholics please)*

Comment: @ninthamigo This is not a question of downvote , And people here must deal me as others , not since I'm muslim if I ask a question must be downvoted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107374/discussion-between-ninthamigo-and-zeraoulia-rafik).

Answer (score 1):

All murder, as mortal sin, cannot usually be forgiven within Catholic teaching without going through confession again, so apart from confession of THAT new sin he/she will have to undergo punishment.

Three points are worth considering however:

**1.** Forgiveness comes ultimately from God and is bestowed on those who genuinely repent even in Roman Catholic circles. Therefore, a Catholic on their death bed may be forgiven even for murder if their repentance is genuine[.](https://catholicsay.com/can-mortal-sins-be-forgiven-without-confessing/) In this way, mediation is not necessary.

**2.** Although not necessary, mediation is valuable. Since the effectiveness of repentance (ar. tawba) depends on sincerity, confessing to another person who will keep you accountable and ensure that you are genuinely repentance and not just saying words[.](https://www.learnreligions.com/the-sacrament-of-confession-542139)

**3.** Only God can forgive sins which is why Jesus forgives sins (Mark 2:7), but by his authority, Jesus gives the right to forgive sins to his saints too - to determine whether repentance is real (John 20:23).

Consider how in Islam your prayers cannot be interrupted by distraction or they are invalidated, in the same way true repentance must be focused on really repenting (which includes penance - trying to fix what you did) or they do not receive genuine forgiveness.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the answer is exactly the same if you killed somebody who wasn't the priest who gave you absolution.

Comment: @DJClayworth, if you say the only who forgive you is God then why you ask others priest or not priest to forgive  u ? Why you are obligated  with that mediation ? The truth guess is to ask your God directly without any means of mediation